# Is the -a flag necessary to create a bash array?

Tags: arrays, bash, associative-array, declare

What is the added value of declaring a bash array with the -a flag like below:

**with flag**

```
declare -a arr1
arr1[0]="array1-zero"
arr1[1]="array1-one"
echo ${arr1[0]}
echo ${arr1[1]}
```

...when the behaviour is the same if you omit the option, like below:

**without -a option**

```
declare arr2
arr2[0]="array2-zero"
arr2[1]="array2-one"
echo ${arr2[0]}
echo ${arr2[1]}
```

The same goes for associative arrays (option -A).
Omitting it renders the same result as providing it.

Comment: For associative arrays, try it with "foo" and "bar" instead of 0 and 1

Comment: Hi, according to the Linux documentation project site, both ways are correct and equal. It's up to you what is preferable. https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html

Comment: @KrassiEm, the ABS is notorious for bad practices in its examples -- it's the same thing to bash that W3Schools is to JavaScript. [The bash-hackers' wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/) and [the BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) are much more attentively maintained.

Comment: Skipping `declare -A` for associative arrays, in particular, is *very* buggy -- your keys get coerced to numbers, so typically, they all take position 0.

Comment: @KrassiEm, ...to speak to said notoriety -- see the timestamps (in UNIX epoch time) at the "abs" factoid entry in the chatbot for the irc.freenode.org #bash channel at http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/abs; you'll see that the ABS has been advised against in that channel since early 2008, so for upwards of a decade now.

Comment: `-a` is not associative arrays it is indexed arrays which is default for bash. That is why OPs examples are the same.

Comment: @Gox, I think the OP knows that already -- that's why they only speak to associative arrays when discussing `-A`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can skip `declare -a` for numerically-indexed arrays, but you **can't** skip `declare -A` for associative arrays. To demonstrate the latter:

```
declare array
array[one]=1
array[two]=2
echo "${array[one]}"
```

...emits:

```
2
```

Why? Let's use `declare -p array` to see:

```
$ declare -p array
declare -a array='([0]="2")'
```

The words `one` and `two` were both coerced to the numeric value `0`, so they overwrote the same key.

---

That said, `declare -a array` isn't a complete noop. Compare:

```
unset array # start from a blank slate
declare -a array
declare -p array
```

...emits:

```
declare -a array='()'
```

---

Whereas if we leave out the `-a`, we see that no type data is assigned, so our variable is assumed to just be a string until it's assigned to in a way that makes it clear that it's supposed to be an array:

```
unset array # start from a blank slate
declare array
declare -p array
```

...emits `declare -- array=""`, unless there's as assignment:

```
unset array # start from a blank slate
declare array
array[0]="zero"
declare -p array
```

...which properly emits `declare -a array='([0]="zero")'`, meaning that in the above code, only after the `array[0]="zero"` line does `array` actually become an array.

Comment: Very clear. So the TLDR is that arrays will be coerced to the correct type, while associative arrays will not. Out of curiosity: Which bash version are you using? I am not getting the output "declare -a array='()'", but rather "declare -a array" when calling declare -p array

Comment: I get `declare -a array` on bash 4.4.23, and `declare -a array='()'` on bash 3.2.57.